# How do I set up asset_host in a jekyll generated site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll, cdn

I have a rails 4 app that properly uses **config.action_controller.asset_host = "xxxxxxx.cdn.com"** to render asset urls to point to a CDN.

The app also has a documentation site that uses **jekyllrb**. Now I want to be able to reference assets from a CDN also but no luck so far.

I'm not able to find documentation about how to setup CDN host for doc site.

I'm trying stuff like this:

```
<img type="image/svg+xml" src="{{ '/docs/images/' | append: page.logo_image  | asset_url}}">
```

but no luck, I just get the image url but no cdn stuff. All that I found are Shoppify links (I think also use Liquid)

Any hint is more than welcome!

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this:

> Jekyll configuration for CloudFront To make it easy to serve my assets
>   from CloudFront, I set up a custom Liquid filter:

```
module Jekyll
  module AssetFilter
    def cdn(input)
      "#{@context.registers[:site].config['cdn']}/#{input}"
    end
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::AssetFilter)
```

> Save this in `_plugins/cdn.rb` off the root of your Jekyll site’s directory.
>
> Then I added a CDN entry to my `_config.yml` file. If I comment this line out, my 
>   assets will be served off of S3 (or localhost if I’m running Jekyll locally).
>
> ```
> cdn: http://cdn.maxmasnick.com
> ```
>
> Whenever I want an asset to be served by the CDN, I pass it through this Liquid filter. For example, in my layout file I have:
>
> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "assets/css/frameless.css" | cdn }}" />`

Source:
http://www.maxmasnick.com/2012/01/21/jekyll_s3_cloudfront/